# What is the dual space of a signed measures with zero mean

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

For locally compact space $X$, Let $C_c(X)$ be the compactly supported, continuous functions on $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$. It is known theorem ([Riesz-Markov-Kakutani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem)) that the dual space of $C_c(X)$ is characterized by Radon measures on $X$, say ${\cal M}(X)$.

My question is, what is the dual space of the subspace.
$$
{\cal M}_0(X) = \left\{\mu \in {\cal M}(X)\bigg| \int_X \mathrm d\mu = 0\right\}
$$

Here is my initial idea:
Consider an equivalence relation for $f, g \in C_c(X)$:
$$
f\sim g \quad \text{if} \quad f(x)-g(x) = c \quad \text{for some }c\in\mathbb{C}, \forall x\in X
$$
and we can consider equivalence class $[f]\subset C_c(X)$. The claim is the family of this equivalence class is dual to ${\cal M}_0(X)$.

The duality pairing is the natural pairing, while it is well-defined because $\mu(f) = \mu(g)$ if $f\sim g$. For metric or norm, $\|[f]\| = \inf_{f\in[f]} \|f\|$ is adopted.

How can I validate the guess, or is there other conditions that I need to refine?

Comment: The duality of the "space of zero-charge measures" with "$F$ mod $C$" was a key ingredient in https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/robert_mackay/MarkovNets09.pdf. There the norm of $f$ in $F$ mod $C$ was defined to be its Lipschitz constant.

Comment: Then I think the induced norm on the difference between two probability distributions corresponds to the Wasserstein distance between them.

Comment: @Ali I like the notation F \ C, thanks for the reference!

Comment: Well where that's used it doesn't stand for $F$ mod $C$ I think, it's just a `\setminus` to exclude the zero element (equivalence class of constant functions) from the $\sup$.